# How to change toolbar menu item text color for pre Lollipop and Lollipop versions

Tags: android, material-design, menuitem, android-toolbar, android-menu

I am using Toolbar for the purpose of material design in my application. Everything working fine but except when it comes to change the menu item text color I am completely stuck up with the solution. I am also posting screenshot of the text that should be taken and code I am using in my application for your reference. I tried several alternate methods like assigning as follows

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

<item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
```

But known of the above solutions works for me.

**Requirement screenshot:**

[image]

Need to change SKIP menu item from black to white color.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>

    </style>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

**manifests**

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|screenLayout|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"></activity>
```

I really dont know where I am committing mistake. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change this

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

to

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

And apply the theme to the toolbar:

```
android:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"
```

You style your widgets and provide themes for your activity.

Comment: To explain why this works, `actionMenuTextColor` is an attribute only added to the `android` namespace in devices supporting 6.0+. To backport this attribute to older devices, the support lib, under `app:actionMenuTextColor` is used instead. Declaring no implicit namespace in `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>` uses the custom namespace: `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`.

Comment: You just saved my day. Thank you!