# toolbar menu item color is white and i cant change it

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

i have this toolbar

```
      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/MyToolbar"
        android:title="@string/emrgnecy_event"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and i have those items

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_x"
    app:showAsAction="always"

android:title="@string/cancel2">

</item>


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_cancel_title"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="cancel"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

and these in main activity

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   // toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.register_to_application));

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    initFragment(new FragmentMainRegister());
}
```

now when i build and run i see the cancel icon but the second item text color is white .. i can click the text but i cant see it because the text is white

so i added actionmenutextcolor in my toolbar style : 
and herer its :

```
 <style name="MyToolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/black</item>

</style>
```

why i cant see my text ?? how to fix it

by the way these tollbar is inflated via fragment callbacks

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181278/how-to-change-toolbar-menu-item-text-color-for-pre-lollipop-and-lollipop-version

Comment: thanks just changed :   <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/black</item> to          <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/black</item>